# Remove border bottom in react-native-material-dropdown

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm using [react-native-material-dropdown-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-dropdown-v2) in my react-native project.

[image]

How can I remove the border bottom? My React Native version is 0.62.2.

Comment: Right-click -> inspect -> find the css selector setting the border and override it. If could find a live demo could tell you exactly.

Comment: This is React Native project not React project. how can I right-click?

Comment: This could be the underline of dropdown style (maybe `itemTextStyle`?).Try to change this property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underline can be removed from the TextInput component of [`react-native-paper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paper)(more details [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html)). You have to pass `underlineColor='transparent'` to Dropdown component.

Comment: Hi Jason,
Now I can remove the underline. Thanks for your help!